# PC side of SPP Bluetooth Profile

Tags: serial, bluetooth, terminal

I have a Bluegiga WT12 module, I want it to connect to a PC with SPP profile. 
How will I handle the PC side?
How will I detect the Bluetooth connection on my PC and get it emulated like a serial cable, so that I can send and receive data with a terminal like RealTerm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a USB bluetooth dongle on your PC (or a laptop with bluetooth built in). The typical way to do this is go to the bluetooth stack software on your PC and scan for devices. Assuming the device is powered, the module will show up as something which supports (perhaps among others) a bluetooth serial port. You can then pair with it (there might be some required passcode, try 0000 or 1234 if the manual doesn't specify). Once you are paired, it will show up as an emulated COM port (typically a high number, like COM5). As a quick test, you can download RealTerm, set it to the bluetooth COM port, and then short the RX and TX pin on your module. Doing this will locally echo back characters typed into the console (normally local echo is off).